# Can I delete published app in alpha testing from google play?

Tags: android, testing, google-play, alpha, google-play-console

I have published my application in alpha testing for testing purpose. Now I want delete it permanently from listing. So, Is it possible to delete published application in alpha mode?

Comment: You can deactivate that. I think You can't completely remove it (I don't try yet), but you can make it inaccessible for other users

Comment: Thanks @Gooziec, Right, but i want to delete because client don't want to listing unused application.

Comment: See http://www.cynosurex.com/Forums/DisplayComments.php?file=Java/Android/Tips_and_Tricks_for_Uploading_Apps_to_Google_Market and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console

Answer (score 2):

If your app is in Alpha and no one has downloaded it. You have to unpublished your app first and then contact Google. They will delete your app for you. I had them delete 1 app for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you has not published your application yet you can delete it. Once you publish it you can only unpublish it.

So you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can only unpublish but cannot delete it. it will not display to user but it will be in your console forever. Delete button only unpublish it.**

> Updated Answer

Now google added this option only if it is not suspended..