# How to remove the unpublished apk from the Google play console account

Tags: android, google-play, publish, in-app-billing, google-account

I am developing an Android application and in this application, I am using "In app billing" features.

I uploaded apk on the google console account and set the product id, price and other required things and saved all the data in the draft.(Application is still in draft mode).
I did not publish my app yet.

After a few minutes, I realized that I uploaded old signed apk file and keystore of this apk has already lost.

Now I want to remove this old apk file and want to upload a new one in draft mode.

**My problems are :**

1. **How to remove the old apk file from the google console account.(In Draft Mode)**
2. **How to upload the new signed apk file with new key store (As I have
   lost my old key store)**

**EDIT:**

I want to publish the app with the same name and with same package name. I do not want to change my app name atleast.

Answer (score 8):

This can now be done by going to `Release management` > `Artifact library` and deleting the APK.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete the artifacts anymore.

Here's a part of my chat with Pete through the built-in help & support.

> Pete: 
>   Thanks for waiting. You can't remove an apk that you've already
>   served. Your next Production apk has to be version code 3 or higher.
>
> Me: 
>   So I can't just delete the artifact of that build?
>
> Pete: 
>   That's correct.

(P.S. He mentioned version code 3 because of my specific issue)

You can try [KOTIOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17548185/7162245)'s answer.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the aab / apk file from the Google Play Console on the App Bundle Explorer under Release Tab

[image]

Then select the apk/aab file you want to delete from the List

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Can we still remove never-published apps from Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180996/can-we-still-remove-never-published-apps-from-google-play):

> Well, the answer is that the strategy still works. If you've never
>   published the app, you can remove all traces of it from Google Play
>   and another publisher account can then upload an app with the same
>   package name. All you need to do is deactivate (if necessary) and then
>   delete all .apk files and the app will disappear from your developer
>   console.
>
> If the app was ever published, this will not work. You can unpublish
>   an app, but you cannot delete any .apk files that were ever active
>   while the app was published. (This behavior is undocumented as far as
>   I can find.) This is unfortunate; it would be nice to be able to
>   completely remove all traces of an app that was never downloaded by
>   anyone. Even better would be a sandbox area that emulated all aspects
>   of Google Play, including buying your own app (and would support doing
>   it through the emulator).
>
> I also discovered that the delays involved in propagating changes to
>   all Google Play servers seems worse than it did a year ago with
>   Android Market. In one case, when testing license responses I had to
>   wait two hours after uploading (but not publishing) an app before the
>   response came back as anything from "NOT_MARKET_MANAGED".

Comment: Hello, I am facing a problem,I published application and by mistake i uploaded old apk and I have also lost my old keystore file. So console is not accepting new apk with new keystore. Now whether i should unpublish app,and can i publish app again with same name and package or not. What better i could do..?

Comment: nope if u want the apk to upload in new version then u need to upload apk with previous keystore only

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by **upload new apk** with upper version 
and the old Apk will deactivated automaticly

[image]